# How $row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) ,is possible in php

Tags: php

We know we can't store a function in variable

```
<?php
$k = echo("hello");
?>
```

or

```
$k = unset($_SESSION['name']);
```

They all will give error. because we can't store a function in variable directly, but how we can use.

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
```

I know `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` function output an array which is stored in variable `$row` . but how a general rule of php is violated. and we are able to store function in a variable

Comment: Why do you think there's a general rule like that? You do it all the time with `$a = array(1, 2, 3);` or `$string = str_replace("foo", "bar", $string);`.

Comment: `echo` and `unset` aren't functions, that's why you can't assign them. They're statements.

Comment: @barmar are you sure

Comment: can you explain bit more

Comment: Read the documentation of `echo` and `unset`. It says "No value is returned". That's because they're not real functions, since all functions return values.

Comment: @barmar function k(){echo "hello";}  ,k() is a function or statement it does not return anyhing

Comment: If a user-defined function doesn't have a return statement, it automatically returns `null`.

Comment: Try `var_dump(k())` and you'll see.

Comment: You aren't trying to store a function. You are trying to store the return value of a function, which does not exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`echo` and `unset` are not really functions. If you check the documentation, you'll see that it says:

> **Return Values**
>   No value is returned

Since no value is returned, you can't assign them to variables.

`mysqli_fetch_assoc()` is an ordinary function. And like any other function, you can assign its return value to a variable, or pass it as an argument to another function, or use it in an expression.

You would have a hard time programming in PHP if you couldn't assign function values to variables. You couldn't write things like:

```
$max = max($var1, $var2);
$current_time = time();
```

Comment: but one more thing. you said user define functions automatically return null value so they are functions. and functions returned value can be store in variabe, So why we  can't use `$k = function h(){return "3";}` , this should have store value 3 in `$k` ,but this does not work , why?

Comment: yes but we can store anonymous function in variable like @beetlejuice said `$k= function(){return "3";} `is possible

Comment: That's not executing the function, it's just defining a function and storing the function definition in the variable.

Answer (score 1):

> We know we can't store a function in a variable

This is not true, but I'll get back to it later.

You are misunderstanding the syntax below:

```
$variable = functionName();
```

This *does not* mean that the function is stored in a variable. It means that *the value returned* by the function is stored in the variable.

So there is nothing special about:

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
```

You should also know as I hinted at in the beginning, that we can in fact store a function in a variable:

```
//store the function in variable $func
$func = function($a, $b){return $a + $b;}

//execute the function stored in variable $func
echo $func(2,8); //prints 10
```

These types of functions -- functions without names -- care called anonymous functions or closures. [See the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php)